# Can an ASP.Net WebForms app work without cookies?

Tags: cookies, webforms

I have an ASP.Net WebForms web app that is supposed to be embedded in a frame in another website. The app has typical WebForms authentication and also uses session. Since third party cookies are [going to be phased out entirely (SameSite=none won't work)](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/privacy-sandbox/overview/#will-samesite-become-irrelevant-after-third-party-cookies-are-deprecated), I'm trying to find a way to keep my app running.

As far as I know WebForms stores session ID in a cookie. There is a 'cookieless' config but then the session ID is put in the query string for everyone to see. Is there a way to make WebForms use localstorage to store session ID?

Or have you figured out a way to make WebForms not depend on cookies to work?

Comment: If you want to continue using form authentication, you need to switch to cookieless mode. It's true that in this case something will be passed via url but it's going to be encrypted,

Comment: I'm not sure this matters. A iFrame would have its own cookie and I don't think that would be considered a 3rd party cookie?